# Why is nginx displaying the wrong website on my server?

Tags: nginx

I have two websites: default-website.com, second-website.com.

When I go to second-website.com I am seeing default-website.com. I do not understand why this is happening. Note default-website.com displays as normal.

This is my setup:

1. DNS is set up so they both point at the same IP address.
2. They both have their own unique websites:

   ```
   /var/www/default-website.com/public_html/index.html

   /var/www/second-website.com/public_html/index.html
   ```
3. This is the contents of /etc/nginx/sites-enabled:

   ```
   lrwxrwxrwx root root default-website.com -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default-website.com

   lrwxrwxrwx root root second-website.com -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/second-website.com
   ```
4. This is the contents of /etc/nginx/sites-available/default-website.com:

   ```
       server {
           listen 80 default_server;
           listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
           root /var/www/default-website.com/public_html;
           index index.html index.htm;
           server_name default-website.com;
           location / {                
                   try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
           }
       }
   ```
5. This is the contents of /etc/nginx/sites-available/second-website.com:

   ```
       server {
           listen 80;
           listen [::]:80;
           root /var/www/second-website.com/public_html;
           index index.html index.htm;
           server_name second-website.com;
           location / {
                   try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
           }
       }
   ```

Can you see anything wrong here? It appears to be set up correctly.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does `nginx -t` show any errors?

Comment: No errors! nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok / 
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I needed to add the "www." version of the domain name to the nginx website config.

So I needed to make this change:

```
server_name second-website.com www.second-website.com;
```

It seems if I tried to go to www.second-website.com it couldn't find it, so it would just load the default website which is default-website.com.

I was able to detect this by trying to load second-website.com (loaded correctly) instead of www.second-website.com (redirected to default-website.com).